# Header partial not rendering properly in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, partials

I created a header partial that I am referring to on different pages. The navigation bar has drop-down menu.

On starting the localserver it works perfectly for the home page. But if I navigate to another page, the dropdown menu does not work anymore. On refreshing the webpage, the dropdown starts working again.

Can anyone guide me as to where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a turbolinks problem.

To simply remove turbolinks, follow [these insturctions](http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4):

1. Remove “gem "turbolinks”“ from your Gemfile and run bundle.
2. Remove ”//= require turbolinks" from application.js.
3. Remove any “data-turbolinks-track” attributes in your layouts.

Or to keep using turbolinks and get it right, read [the rails guides on turbolinks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks). The short story is that when you click to a new page, your document.ready event (which presumably is what you're using) won't fire, so your navigation won't be set up correctly. You need to use the "on page change" event instead.

Answer (score 0):

As joshua said, it sounds like a turbolinks problem.
if you are using jquery, [jQuery Turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) could be solve that problem easily.